# Thousands of OkHttp related issues reported daily (connection, unknown host, dns, etc)

Tags: android, kotlin, dns, retrofit, okhttp

## Setup

I have an app in production used by thousands of users daily.

I'm using retrofit2 version 2.9.0 (latest)

My `build.gradle` below.

```
def retrofitVersion = '2.9.0'
api "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${retrofitVersion}"
api "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:${retrofitVersion}"
api "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:${retrofitVersion}"
api "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${retrofitVersion}"
```

I integrated Firebase Crashlytics and made it so that app would report any API related exceptions in `try-catch` blocks.

e.g.

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch {
    try {
        val response = myRepository.getProfile()
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            // continue with some business logic
        } else {
            Log.e(tag, "error", RunTimeException("some error")
        }
    } catch (throwable: Throwable){
        Log.e(tag, "error thrown", throwable)
        crashlytics.recordException(throwable)
    }
}
```

## Knowns

Now in Crashlytics, I get THOUSANDS of reports daily saying there were some errors.
Before I get to those errors, I want to assure you that users ARE connected to internet with proper network permissions. I see logs that users are opening other contents at the time. So these errors seem to be really random.

## Erros

1. UnknownHostException

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "my-host-address.com": No address associated with hostname
       at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:156)
       at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
       at okhttp3.Dns$Companion$DnsSystem.lookup(Dns.java:5)
...
Caused by android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
       at libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Linux.java)
       at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:74)
       at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:200)
       at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:74)
       at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:135)
       at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
...
```

2. ConnectionException

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to my-host-address.com/123.123.123.123:443
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:146)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:191)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:257)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:47)
...
Caused by java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to my-host-address.com/123.123.123.123 (port 443) from /:: (port 0) after 10000ms: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:142)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
...
Caused by android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
       at libcore.io.Linux.connect(Linux.java)
       at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.connect(ForwardingOs.java:94)
       at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:138)
       at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.connect(ForwardingOs.java:94)
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:173)
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:134)
...
```

3. SocketTimeoutException

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
       at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException(Http2Stream.java:4)
       at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.exitAndThrowIfTimedOut(Http2Stream.java:8)
       at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.java:24)
       at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http2ExchangeCodec.java:5)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.java:2)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:145)
...
```

4. Another SocketTimeoutException

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SSL handshake timed out
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(NativeCrypto.java)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:387)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:234)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:72)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:52)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:196)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:257)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:47)
```

And lastly, what makes me think it's not my server issue is that I get this kind of error when I request banner ads to Google server as well.
I get thousands of reports of the following

```
{   "Message": "Error while connecting to ad server: Failed to connect to pubads.g.doubleclick.net/216.58.195.130:443",   "Cause": "null",   "Response Info": {     "Adapter Responses": [],     "Response ID": "null",     "Response Extras": {},     "Mediation Adapter Class Name": ""   },   "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",   "Code": 0 }
```

from Google ads SDK's `onAdFailedToLoad` listener.

## Attempt

I tried to find some solutions in Retrofit2/OkHttp3 github issues, SO community, and everyone says there may be some network permission issues or network connection problem itself. But I know users are connected to internet and not using some sort of proxy. I worked with customer service team and they walked through with users, and they did not find any network issues.

Any insight would be helpful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: We are facing the same issues for the past week. It is working on some users but not working on others. It was very difficult to reproduce. The only way I could reproduce the issue by using AdGuard app. When it is enabled, I was receiving the same error `java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host`. When I disabled it, the error persisted. I had to restart the app or disconnect from the wifi and then connect again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think that would definitely cause the issue, but on our side users reported that they don't have any ad blocker/proxy enabled :(

Comment: Yeah, that goes for us as well. I thought users have some adblocker installed, but when we checked no one had any adblockers or proxy enabled. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: @SaehunSeanOh have you been able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I had these issues too. After a long time, I have realized most of these problems are related to the `SSL certificate validation` by android in different devices. Some devices are not able to validate your certificate because it does not exist in their `pre-installed system CA certificates`. You need to put the certificate in your app to avoid this issue. You can do this in the following steps:

`Export` your SSL certificate to a file. (There are different ways to do this for example using a browser). Rename it to a simple name for example `mycert`.
Put this file in the `raw` folder in this path `res > raw`.

Make an XML file called `network_security_config.xml` in the `xml` folder at this path `res > xml`.

Paste this lines in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">my-host-address.com</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/mycert"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

change the `my-host-address.com` in the `domain` tag to your desired API address.

Add this line:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

to the application tag in your manifest file like so:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/app_ic_luncher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppCompatTheme"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    ...
```

Make a new build and hopefully, it works for you.

Comment: Pretty sure this is indeed the sulotion. Alternatively switching certificates for the host domain to one that is more commonly recognized. I specifically encountered certificate issues on huaweii devices, because they simply did not have my cert in the preinstalled system CA.

Comment: 97% of users experiencing this issue is from Samsung users using Galaxy S10 and later devices. And this happens to now only our domain, but also google owned domains (subdomain of doubleclick.net), so I'm not sure how this is possible. Regardless I'll try this solution and let you know!

Comment: before bounty expires, I awarded this answer anyways. Thank you for the reply. I'll let you know if this works.

Comment: As Joachim said you can use more recognized CA alternatively. I hope my solution works for you but if it doesn't please let me know to find another way. @SaehunSeanOh

Comment: We are using certs from cloudflare... I think that's pretty well known ;p

Comment: @SaehunSeanOh did implementing SSL certificate validation solved your issue?

Comment: @himanshuMori We haven't really use this approach because we didn't want to include a certificate in our app bundle, especially when we know for sure 1. the issuer is one of the biggest certificate issuers, and 2. devices with problem are well known manufacturers. This hasn't really improved since this time, so we think this has something to do with ISPs of the users

Comment: I have same issue that from an unamed brand of android screen (installed in elevator for showing videos), while other hundreds of PC clients are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue with dns resolution for certain users. The url works if they for example tries to access it from a browser. Implementing an alternative DNS resolution, like DnsOverHttps using Cloudflare could work, if it doesn't make sense to invest more time finding a root cause.

```
val bootstrapClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()
val dns = DnsOverHttps.Builder().client(bootstrapClient)
        .url("https://1.1.1.1/dns-query".toHttpUrl())
        .includeIPv6(false)
        .build()
val httpClient = bootstrapClient.newBuilder().dns(dns).build()
```

Alternatively wrapping that in something first trying the system one and then DnsOverHttps as a fallback if the system one doesn't behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

About 2 years earlier I faced an issue like this. The previous answer was not my case fortunately (I tried after clearing DNS cache). I talked to my ISP about this problem they said something about caching request and response. They also told me to wait for 24 hours the server/ISP will release the cache then try. I waited and it worked. I don't know how this happened or why it worked.